# Group markers google maps on React Native Maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am using React Native map from https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues. how to use marker clusters to display a large number of markers on a map using react-native-map component?
Something like this
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/213.
This still an open issue. maybe in future, this feature will release.

Comment: Nguyên Hoàng, thank you for response.